# Qt Ui Application Screen Orientation

Tags: c++, ios, qt, ipad

I am a newbie trying mobile application development using Qt. I am currently trying to deploy my Qt UI application on iOS devices. The application runs perfectly on my iPad. The only problem is the screen orientation. I can see only half of the application when I rotate my iPad to the landscape mode.

I searched through this site, but most of the sites actually talk about Qt Quick application solutions. My application is a Qt UI application.

Comment: Are you on 5.3.x with an iOS 8 device? It could be probably the rotation bug a lot of people are experiencing in quick application (should affect also non-quick applications). It has been fixed in 5.4, give the beta a try.

Comment: Thanks BaCaRoZzo..I'll give it a try now..Ill update as soon as possible..

Answer (score 0):

As BaCaRoZzo suggested, it was indeed an issue with Qt 5.3.2. I downloaded the beta version of Qt 5.4.0 for mac and tried running it. Now I don't get the orientation error.

Thanks BaCaRoZzo and everyone.

Regards
Alok